# Where do VBScript (ASP) Server Components reside?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm new to ASP, VBScript and am trying to figure out how to change some text on a webpage.

**What I want to do:**
Change some text in a web page

**The problem:**
The web page (.asp) text seems to be generated by code that looks like this: ***<% Set MyAd = Server.CreateObject("ETFramework11.WPLoginPage") %>*** and I cannot directly see the text that I want to change.

**Question:**
Where does the file(s) housing the *ETFramework11* or *WPLoginPage* reside physically? (assuming that they reside in separate files somewhere) What are the file types? What do they look like?

Comment: It's probably in a .vb file on the server but it could be named anything.  The object that is being created is defined inside the file, not by the file name.

Comment: Even if you can track down the DLL following @mdms correct and complete answer you'll need the sources of this component to make the desired changes.

Comment: @Filburt thanks for your input. Could you tell me where generally to look for component sources?

Comment: where did you get the component from?

Comment: Usually source code which is compiled into a DLL isn't stored on the webserver. If someone asks you to modify the output of a software component they should provide you the source code. If you were told "It's all there." look out for .cls (VB6 source) files and .vbp (VB6 project) files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateObject` is used to instantiate a COM object. So `ETFramework11.WPLoginPage` is an object in a DLL somewhere. You will need to find out where that object pulls the files from if at all - if not, then it is embedded in the DLL and I would contact the vendor.

You can find out where the DLL is located by searching for the object name (i.e. `ETFramework11.WPLoginPage` in the registry).

Answer (score 0):

They are called COM components which is a spec different technologies can implement. I think most of the ASP world implemented them with a technology called ActiveX.

The file can theoretically reside anywhere. The system is told about the COM components through the "Regsvr32" command.